# Div displacement in Google Chrome

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have three Divs,Surrounding Div is "MainDiv",
Inside it Top Div is "UpperDiv"
and Lower one is the "FooterDiv".

In Mozilla everything goes fine but in Chrome "FooterDiv" is Displaced to the "Top Right"
of my Aspx Page...i.e. **on the Top Right side, adjacent to MainDiv**.

It should appear at bottom of this page.
What to Do in such case ?

Thanks Developers .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using floats, that's your problem.  Don't use floats for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: for "UpperDiv" make clear:both and remove and any float:left if you mentioned for the "lowerdiv" and "UpperDiv".

Comment: If he has to use clear: both on basic vertical div structures, he's got very questionable layout.   It'd be better to see his code before recommending clear: both.